# How can Angular detect impacted datas inside a function?

Tags: angularjs

I just ran a test i wad expecting to fail, but it works:

I have a collaction of 20 players.
Each players have a number of points.
I want to display into an input the player that have the biggest amount of points.

So what i am going to do is to iterate the collection to find the best one.
So i bind a function that iterate the collection and not the collection itself, and Angular is able to know it has to run the function when the collection is updated, how is that possible ? Does Angular restart all the collection's methods when something is updated into it or is there a smart system which enables it to know which methods are impacted ?

**HTML**

```
<input value="{{findTheBest().name}}">
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.Players = [ { name: 'toto', points: 10 }, { name: 'john', points: 100 } ];
  $scope.findTheBest = function() {
    TheBest = $scope.Players[0];
      for (var Player in $scope.Players) {
        if ($scope.Players[Player].points > TheBest.points)
          TheBest = $scope.Players[Player];
       }

      console.log('The Best = '+TheBest.name);
      return TheBest;
    };

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.Players[0].points += 500;
    }, 5000);
});
```

[Here is a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/M7EYYrGpd5CJI1QIoQ0q?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Angular isn't doing anything *too* smart here.  When an Angular $digest runs, the watch queue is looped through (in your case `findTheBest().name` would be in the watch queue).

Then, Angular does dirty checking. So, it basically calls twice during the digest and compares the values.  So, the function will be called twice and if the values are different the update is made.

[This is a good blog post](http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/17/angular_is_slow/) that describes what the Angular internals are doing.

Answer (score 1):

For each attribute interpolation: `{{ expression }}` angular registers a `$watch`.

When a `$digest` happens , angular iterates over all registered `$watchers` and evaluates the `watchExpressions` against their scope.

When your app is initialized, with a first digest loop it evaluates the expression which in your case is also calling a function on that scope. And then your function is registering a `$timeout`.

`$timeout` by default triggers another digest loop which in turn triggers another $timeout and so on.

---

Actually the expression is evaluated every `$digest` which can happen multiple times on each digest loop. So on each digest loop your function can be called multiple times and set multiple `$timeout` which is probably not the behavior you expected.

Read more here: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html